# Work ? android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize + onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android

I'm using (I'm don't know if is a bug 16/12/2015) `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize` +
`onConfigurationChanged` (Awesome) you can get full control from XML and Java, Note (normally can't use android:configChanges with onConfigurationChanged ) I'm using 2 methods and work correctly.

I'm wondering why run correctly, previously never Work.

Comment: I think is so easy, put vote-1, that learn java or tell theory

Comment: some people just came here to downvote

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) states the following for `android:configChanges`:

> Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called.

So it defines that what you are doing in your code is the correct way it should work. `onConfigurationChanged()` is ONLY called for an event, if the event is stated in `android:configChanges` of the activity.